# JSF 2.0 + axis2 integration is it possible?

Tags: java, web-services, jsf-2, apache-axis, myeclipse

[image]

Is it possible to implement `axis2` in an `JSF 2.0` project ?? it seems I cannot do that because it pops up an error saying : `javaserver faces 2.0 requires dynamic web module 2.5`, and `axis2` requires dynamic module `2.2` or `2.3` does anyone have any solution please ??

Comment: What are server are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this on MyEclipse 10.7.1 and had no problem. I just added JSF capabilities to the web project (right click on the project and go to MyEclipse->Add JSF Capabilities, selecting 2.0. Then I set the Axis2 runtime in the preferences (I have an old Axis2 1.5.4 runtime). Then I went to the preferences page you showed, for the project, and added Axis2. I got no errors. For the Axis2 runtime preferences page, you need to have the WTP Extras enabled (Window->Preferences->General->Capabilities->Advanced then open MyEclipse Standard Tools and select WTP Extras before clicking OK).

I'm not sure if the release of MyEclipse is significant but, if you're not on the latest (10.7.1) it would probably be a good idea to update your installation first.

Comment: You created a dynamic web project 2.5 or web project 3.0 ?? because the problem is when your creating web project 3.0 and you cannot use JSF 2.0 with this dynamic web project 2.5 some features wont work

Comment: Sorry, I created a default Web Project, which gave me a Web 2.5 project. Creating a Web Project for JEE6 gave me a project with Web 3.0 and I couldn't add Axis2 to this. From searching for the problem, it seems that Axis2 can only be used with Web 2.5 (and below), at least so far as WTP is concerned. MyEclipse is based on WTP, in this area, so there is no workaround to get the Axis2 tooling for Web 3.0. It seems that to use Axis2 with Web 3.0, you'll have to manually do the work. Alternatively, you can use the non-Axis2 web services functionality in MyEclipse.